# Бесконечный деплой NodeJS сервера на Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku

```html
C:\Users\vovat\WebstormProjects\Blog\ServerBlog>git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 16, done.
Counting objects: 100% (16/16), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 59.91 KiB | 2.85 MiB/s, done.
Total 16 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 10.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.16.3...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.9.0
remote:        Resolving yarn version 1.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing yarn (1.17.3)...
remote:        Installed yarn 1.17.3
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (yarn.lock)
remote:        yarn install v1.17.3
remote:        [1/4] Resolving packages...
remote:        [2/4] Fetching packages...
remote:        info fsevents@1.2.9: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
remote:        info "fsevents@1.2.9" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
remote:        [3/4] Linking dependencies...
remote:        [4/4] Building fresh packages...
remote:        Done in 11.53s.
remote:
remote: -----> Build
remote:        Running build (yarn)
remote:        yarn run v1.17.3
remote:        $ yarn babel-transform &&  yarn start
remote:        $ babel src -d dist
remote:        src/controllers/PostController.js -> dist/controllers/PostController.js
remote:        src/index.js -> dist/index.js
remote:        src/model/PostModel.js -> dist/model/PostModel.js
remote:        $ node dist/index.js
remote:        Node app is running at localhost:5000
```

```html
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import PostController from "./controllers/PostController";
import experss from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
const Post = new PostController();

const app = experss();
const connectionString  = "some url";


app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

mongoose.connect(connectionString, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send(`<h1>Started</h1>`)
})
app.post('/posts', Post.create);
app.get('/posts', Post.read);
app.put('/posts/:id', Post.update);
app.delete('/posts/:id', Post.delete);

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
})
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В чем проблема? Опишите подробнее, что вы хотите получить в итоге?

Comment: деплой сервера на heroku  не прекращаеться, всё сделал по официальном туториале

Comment: хочу просто чтобы сервер работал удаленно на heroku

Comment: package.json покажите

Comment: Вся проблема была в скрипте build("node index.js") в файле package.json...он не нужен поскольку heroku сам знает что сбилдить надо